# Where I define wrapper function and functional interface for exception handling on stream

Tags: java, stream

While using streams, I learned how to handle exceptions using functional interfaces and wrapper functions.

If so, what is the best way to structure the package?

Is it defined together in the class where stream is used? Or should I create a separate common class and define the wrapper function in it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends. If you have one instance of using this technique, then it probably makes sense to simply use an functional interface and a wrap function that are part of the class which utilizes it. If you are using this same pattern in several places (and they all have the same function interface signature) then you can define the functional interface at the package level and put the wrap function in a utility class.

Comment: Just as a comment. I'm not fond of this entire pattern. It doesn't really do much, and adds boilerplate to your project for little return value. I think it is also arguable that you should simply return values and if some of them represent "something went wrong with this particular function call" then you can deal with it there.